# Chromebook with linkbucks virus

Tags: virus, google-chrome-os, virus-removal, chromebook

I just bought a new Samsung Series 3 Chromebook with the Google Chrome OS operating system. one of the main advantages of this system is that they are supposed to be impervious to viruses.

While browsing the web, when I click a link I will often get redirected to a "linkbucks" site instead of the site I am trying to go to. Other time ads for online game will popup at random. It really seems like I have a virus, but I can't find any information online about anyone else who is having this problem.

I have done a complete reset by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on the login screen, but the virus is still there.

What is causing the redirect to linkbucks and how do I remove it?

Comment: Does the same problem happen in another machine? If so, your router might be compromised. I doubit your chromebook has a virus.

Comment: I suspected the router too, but we have two other laptop and two phone that use the same router and they haven't had any problems. What else could I do to rule out the router?

Comment: Sanity check: Does the chromebook connect to the same access point?

Comment: ChromeOS has sandboxing technology, which allows viruses to be stored at one location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have not been able to reproduce the problem after the first day. I can only assume we accidently connected to the neighbors wireless access points instead of ours and that their router is compromised.